# Salesforce, SOQL, Developer Console, sObject is not supported

Tags: salesforce, soql

In Developer Console in SOQL I try to select Product, but that is not possible.

```
SELECT Id FROM Product
```

Error:
"sObject type 'Product' is not supported."
[image](https://pasteboard.co/JSgDvnf.png)

I found this advice:
"There is a checkbox 'Use tooling API' at the bottom of the screen. Uncheck it if it is checked and try."
[from here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ar85IAC)
But, it didn't help. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual object's name is [`Product2`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm).

> As of API version 8.0, the Product object is no longer available.
> Requests that contain Product are refused, and responses don’t contain
> the Product object.

Here's the Entity Relationship Diagram: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm

API v8 would be ancient history, 14 years ago ;) https://gs0.salesforce.com/services/data/

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought that [Product](https://pasteboard.co/JSoSlsq.png) is Product. I was wrong. Product, is Product2. :)

Comment: Schema Builder has setting somewhere to use API names for tables and fields instead of labels. There are few inconsistencies laying around, File is actually `ContentDocument` for example